# DataSet Add Column gives ArgumentException

Tags: c#, dataset

using the following code and the following xml, I get an ArgumentException when adding a new Column to a Table in a DataSet.

Though, I have no Idea why, because the specified column does not exist anywhere in the xml before.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        set.ReadXml("../../test.xml");

        DataColumn column = new DataColumn("mobile", typeof(string));
        set.Tables["Contact"].Columns.Add(column); //exception is thrown here

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

using the following test.xml:

```
<ROOT>
    <CONTACT TYPE="PHONE" SIGN="HOME">123</CONTACT>
    <CONTACT TYPE="PHONE" SIGN="BUSINESS">456</CONTACT>
</ROOT>
```

Exception I get is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional Information: Cannot add a nested relation or 
an element column to a table containing a SimpleContent column
```

I don't really understand why I get the exception, and what it means. Can someone enlighten me please, thank you.

Comment: I think reading the xml is making the datatable capital letters "CONTACT" not "Contact".

Comment: this is case insensitive, but if it helps, I'll change the code and get the same error

Comment: You have content in your XML nodes. This is gonna be bad. Remove the content and try it. It will not throw the exception. If this XML is fixed then `DataSet`s may not be your optimal choice.

Try out a proper XML deserializer Like `System.Xml.Linq` or the other built in XML serializers: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=.net%20xml%20deserialization